# Getting actions of changed files from TeamCity's REST Api

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity's REST api to get the list of changed files for a specific change. 
I do it like this:
http://teamcityserver:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:

In the result, I am getting a bunch of "file" xml nodes. However, for each file, I would like to know the action done on it (was this file added? removed? edited?) and this information is not present in the file nodes.

Is there a way I can get this information from the api?

(I am using TeamCity 9, if that's relevant)

Answer (score 1):

I just got a response from TeamCity support saying that it's not possible:

"Unfortunately it is not possible to get the file action via REST API".